# Use lodash or es6 to write a function that takes in an object with deeply nested properties and returns a new object with only select properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, lodash

I have an object that has many unnecessary properties and deeply nested properties that I want.

My goal is to take this first object and return a new object with only the desired fields that I want.

Heres an example of the big a the big object, and an example of what I'm trying to reshape it to:

```
let bigObject = {
  id: 1,
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c',
  vLines: [
    {
      vouchId: 1,
      vouchLineId: 1,
      dontNeedThisProperty: 'blah',
      a2: 'a',
      rejection: 'vLine rejection reason 1',
      dLines: [
        {
          id: 1,
          rejection: 'dline rejection reason 1',
          amount: 12345,
          vouchLineId: 1
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

I want to get it trimmed down to look like this:

```
let newObject = {
  id: 1,
  vLines: [
    {
      vouchId: 1,
      vouchLineId: 1,
      rejection: 'vLine rejection reason 1'
    }
  ],
  dLines: [
    {
      id: 1,
      rejection: 'dline rejection reason 1',
      vouchLineId: 1
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a redux selector that is getting me part way through, but I'm having trouble getting to those deeply nested properties for dLine

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { isEqual, pick } from 'lodash';

export const testSelector = createSelector(
  nestedSelectedSelector,
  vouch => pick(vouch, ['id', 'vLines'])
);
```

Comment: you're probably looking for https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr

Comment: What kind of trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't pretty or clean, but this produces the output that you're expecting. There is probably a more-efficient way to do the `flatMap()` function on the `dLines` so that you don't have to do another `map()` afterwards, but this was my quick-and-dirty way of doing it.

```js
let bigObject = {
  id: 1,
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c',
  vLines: [
    {
      vouchId: 1,
      vouchLineId: 1,
      dontNeedThisProperty: 'blah',
      a2: 'a',
      rejection: 'vLine rejection reason 1',
      dLines: [
        {
          id: 1,
          rejection: 'dline rejection reason 1',
          amount: 12345,
          vouchLineId: 1
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
};

// How you said you wanted it to look...
/*
let newObject = {
  id: 1,
  vLines: [
    {
      vouchId: 1,
      vouchLineId: 1,
      rejection: 'vLine rejection reason 1'
    }
  ],
  dLines: [
    {
      id: 1,
      rejection: 'dline rejection reason 1',
      vouchLineId: 1
    }
  ]
}*/

const newObject = _.chain(bigObject)
  .pick(['id'])
  .set('vLines', _.chain(bigObject.vLines).map(vLine => _.pick(vLine, ['vouchId', 'vouchLineId', 'rejection'])).value())
  .set('dLines', _.chain(bigObject.vLines).flatMap('dLines').map(dLine => _.pick(dLine, ['id', 'vouchLineId', 'rejection'])).value())
  .value();
  
console.log(newObject)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```